# Using latest Ember.js (1.0.0-PRE.3) with yeoman

Tags: ember.js, javascript-framework, yeoman

The **[ember.js](http://emberjs.com)** team just released the new version of the ember framework version `1.0.0-pre.3` this version includes the new "router" API that I'm very eager to use.

I'm about to start a new app and **[yeoman](http://yeoman.io)** is in my workflow to help, but the yeoman ember-generator uses the `1.0.0-pre.2` version (wich has the deprecated router API implementation) for the generation of the projects boilerplates, but I would like to use the new version `1.0.0-pre.3` in my new project, and the easy way to do it is very hacky, it would be to change the ember.js lib directly in the yeoman templates directories and update the version number in the corresponding generator script that uses it, I've already made a test changing it this way and it would work, but this way I would "break" my yeoman installation, this is not a good option I think.

So my final master question is, how would I go about to update yeoman to use the new ember lib without hacking? Or should I maybe make a fork of the project https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman create a new branch for a new ember-generator (using the latest ember lib obviously) and make a pull request hoping to get accepted? Can someone "yeoman savvy" point me in the right direction here? I just want to make it the right way... if there is one :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ok, this page sais it all: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Generators - I'm going to make my own generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just manually update the ember lib in your project.

Yeoman 1.0 will have support for updating libs transparently.

Comment: ok thanks, this is what I'm going to do, but I can't make use of the generators like "ember:controller" "ember:model" etc. just yet... looking forward to version 1.0 :)